# Can I avoid to add in mongoDB null value for some field?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I m trying to develop a Spring boot with MongoDB and my problem is that I don't want that a user to put in the DB **empty** or `null` value for some field.

I already tried the option that I found on the web but it didn't work.

**Code:**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Document(collection = "product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @NotNull(message = "brand must not be null")
    private String brand;

    @NotNull(message = "barCode must not be null")
    private String barCode;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate importDate;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate expireDate;

    @NotNull(message = "price must not be null")
    private Double price;

    private Double deal;

    @NotNull(message = "the quantity must not be null")
    private Integer quantity;
}
```

Comment: Maybe have a default value when the field value is null or empty. What kind of field is it? Are you looking for validation - where? On the database server, or the application server level? If you dont want the user to put in empty or null value, maybe it can be taken care at client-side validation.

Comment: I know I can put more line in the view, but I do not want to use a lot of if statement, it can`t be like sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using

> @NotNull

Which is used for validation a model.

For omitting storing `null` values to *DB* you should use:

```
@Column(nullable=false)
private String brand;
```

**UPDATE**:

Looks like your schema has been already generated.
You didn't share the DB configuration of your project.

If you are using Spring Boot, you have to set at `application.properties` additional properties to make it work:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.check_nullability=true
```

However, it will help do not store `null` values.

For preventing to store empty values you should add for string fields:

```
@Size(min=1)
```

If you want to validate *Integer* or *Double* that they have values more than `0`, use `@Min`:

```
@Min(value = 1L, message = "The price must be positive")
private Double price;
```

Comment: it doesn`t work

Comment: @Robs updated the answer

Comment: It didn`t work but I just add more if statement so the user must add, thanks anyway